# py-indent-or-complete leaves the *Python Completion* buffer open

Tags: python, completion, elpy

I experience when using `TAB` bound to `py-indent-or-complete` that it gives me completion suggestions. however when leaving, or deciding the completion, the `*Python Completion*` buffer is left open instead of getting buried. I also experience that after tab completing the word at point a newline is needlessly inserted moving me one line down.

What are the underlying settings to configure these two things when using `py-indent-or-complete`?

Answer (score 1):

This would constitute a bug. Please check out current trunk either at

https://launchpad.net/python-mode

or at some distributor. AFAIK melpa.org ships it.
Using el-get should work too.

In case bug still occurs, please file a report at

https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode

attaching some example code which triggers it - for now can't see it.